# Adding count values in a temporary array

Tags: php, arrays

I am counting the difference between two days in inside a foreach loop.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    # code...

    //$temp[$value->user_id]=$value->user_id;
    $count_dates=daysBetween($value->user_source_history_added,$current_date);
    $tmp_array[$count_dates][] = $count_dates;
}
```

On debugging tmp_array, I get something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 3
        )
)
```

Now I want to count the number of 0's, 1's, 2's, 3's, etc. So for now there are 7 0's and 1 1's and 4 3's. 
How do I get the count of all these numbers and how do I limit it that I get only the count till Array 20??

I tried this:

```
foreach($tmp_array as $tmp_val)
{
    count($tmp_val)
}
```

But I get the count of main array that is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update `if($count_array<=20){}`

This is a general solution, it will take in consideration any number in you have in your $temp array and it will store this number as his record in this array

```
$found_numbers=array();
$results=array();
$count_array=0;
    foreach($tmp_array as $first_array)
{   $count_array++;
    foreach($first_array as $second_array)
    { 
      if($count_array<=20){
        if (in_array($second_array, $found_numbers)) {
          $results[$second_array][0]++;
        }
        else{
         array_push($found_numbers,$second_array);
         $results[$second_array] = array();
         array_push($results[$second_array],1);
         }
      } 
    }
}
```

//to get how many you have number n in your array you have only to type print($results[n][0]);

```
print($results[0][0]); //will give you 7
print($results[n][0]);  //will give the record of the number n in your array
```

Comment: It breaks when the value of n is not there. Undefined offset

Comment: @phantomphoenix Easy, just add this at the end: `foreach($found_numbers as $number) { print "the record of the number ".$number." is:".$results[$number][0]."\n"; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of everything added together:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($tmp_array as $tmp_subarray)
{
    foreach($tmp_subarray as $tmp_val) {
        if($count < 20) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the amount of 1s, 2s, 3s, etc:

```
$count = array();
foreach($tmp_array as $tmp_subarray)
{
    foreach($tmp_subarray as $tmp_val) {
        if($count[$temp_val]) {
            $count[$temp_val]++;
        } else {
            $count[$temp_val] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count all the values of an array no matter how many dimensions assuming the values are arrays or numbers. This will run until the main array has reached $key == 20.

```
$total = 0;

function addToTotal($number) {
    glob $total;
    $total = $total + $number;
}

function countArrayValues($array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array ($value) {
            countArrayValues($value);
        } else {
            addToTotal($value);
        }
    }
}

$mainArray; // <-- your array;

foreach($mainArray as $key => $value) {
    if($key <= 20) {
        countArrayValues($value);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: This gives me a series of 0's. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$array_number_of_numbert = array();
foreach($tmp_array as $tmp_val_num => $tmp_val)
{
    $array_number_of_numbert[$tmp_val_num]= $tmp_val;
}
for($i = 0; $i <=20; $i++)
{
    if(isset($array_number_of_numbert[$i])) echo count($array_number_of_numbert[$i])." ". $i."'s\n";
}
```